# How to specify custom semantic roles in flutter semantics?

Tags: flutter, accessibility, semantics

I'd like to use flutter's [semantics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html) to make my page more accessible.

From what I understand there are web standards that define which elements on the page should have which role, as defined e.g. [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/). I'd like to use these roles in my flutter web page as well.

When I look at the semantic tree of youtube.com, I see a very clean semantic tree with the proper roles for all the elements, e.g. the Navigation is shown as "navigation", tab items are shown as "tab" and so on:

[Semantic tree of youtube.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBPCH.png)

However, when I look at my page, most of the widgets are shown simply as generic (or "group" for the containers).

[Semantic tree of my flutter page, all elements shown as "group" or "generic"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otbxF.png)

As a start I want to show my navigation as "navigation" and the tab items as "tab", as in the youtube tree.
This is a simplified example of what I'm trying:

```
return Semantics(
      container: true,
      label: 'Navigation',
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Semantics(
            link: true,
            selected: true,
            child: Clickable(
              child: const Text('Tab 1'),
              onClick: () => print('foo'),
            ),
          ),
          Semantics(
            link: true,
            selected: false,
            child: Clickable(
              child: const Text('Tab 2'),
              onClick: () => print('bar'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

(Side note: The "Clickable" widget is basically a wrapper for GestureDetector with some specified default behaviour.)

As you see in the screenshot above, the tabs are just shown as "generic" which is not so helpful. The "selected" attribute (to indicate the active tab) is not reflected in the semantic tree at all.

I experimented with the input arguments for the Semantics Widget for some time now, but I've seen only very few roles actually reflected in the semantic tree. E.g. when I set the "button" property to true, the link will have the role of a button, if I set the "toggled" property of the semantic, it will show as "switch". Example:

```
    return Semantics(
      container: true,
      label: 'Navigation',
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Semantics(
            link: true,
            selected: true,
            toggled: true,
            child: Clickable(
              child: const Text('Tab 1'),
              onClick: () => print('foo'),
            ),
          ),
          Semantics(
            link: true,
            selected: false,
            toggled: true,
            child: Clickable(
              child: const Text('Tab 2'),
              onClick: () => print('bar'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

will lead to:
[Semantic tree of flutter page, showing "switch" as role for the tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWc5C.png)

How can I specify proper roles for my widgets? Are there any examples for doing so?
Thanks in advance :)